# Instagram switch account programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, instagram, instagram-api

Instagram recently allowed users to switch between there accounts. I made an app which allows user to take pic , apply special effects and share it on to instagram to there default account. Is there a iphone hook or other way which will allow users to select which account they want to share, from my app instead of switching accounts from instagram app.